# Laravel - PHP array_push produces numbered indices to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax request that will update certain stats on the page.
My ajax controller is like this:

```
   public function getStats (Request $request) {

    $now = new DateTime();
    $stats = [];

    $remindersCount = Reminder::where('created_by', '=', Auth::user()->id )
                        ->where('date', '<=', $now)
                        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                        ->count();

    array_push($stats,array("remindersCount"=>$remindersCount));

    $Name= Auth::user()->name;

    array_push($stats,array("Name"=>$Name));

    .... more queries and array_push ...

    return response()->json((object) $stats);
```

the response received by javascript is:

```
{"0":{"remindersCount":1},"1":{"Name":"Ahmed"},"2":{"favoritesCount":1},
"3":{"myCallCount":13},"4":{"totalCalls":13},"5":{"totalClients":7},
"6":{"sysVersion":"1.0"}}
```

So in Javascript I cannot use `reponse.remindersCount` to access its value, I have to use `response[0].remindersCount`.

I know the reason is that array_push adds numeric indices in php. How can I produce a simple `{{key,value},{key,value}}` object without numbers?

Comment: If you don't want to use an array, why do you create an array in PHP?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden this is what I could think of. What is a better solution? I would like to append query results to a variable and at the end send it to the view.

Comment: Instead of using array_push, can you build the stats array at the end? Also, if you're returning an array, Laravel automatically converts it to json, so you can just return $stats directly like `return $stats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$stats = [];

$remindersCount = Reminder::where('created_by', '=', Auth::user()->id )
                    ->where('date', '<=', $now)
                    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                    ->count();

$stats['remindersCount'] = $remindersCount;
$stats['name'] = Auth::user()->name;

.... more queries ...

return response()->json($stats);
```

Comment: This indeed changed the response from object to array but I still cannot access it in Javascript without the index.
`console.log(response[0].remindersCount)` returns 1
`console.log(response.remindersCount)` returns undefined

Comment: Please take a look at the updated version.. You should do it like that if you want to access directly response.remindersCount

Comment: Next time incase you need alternative, that's why you have `array_merge()` but for this case, the answer given is simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you define you array in the end when you have all the variables you can use this syntax:

```
$stats = [
   'remindersCount => $remindersCount,
   'name' => $Name,
   ....
];
```

if you have to do it before you can use this syntax:

```
$stats['remindersCount] = $remindersCount;
$stats['name] = $Name;
```